# listings caption is distorted

Tags: listings, captions, acm

I used listing for listing the codes like:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall}

% Package to generate and customize Algorithm as per ACM style
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{ALGORITHM}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapHSkip{0pt}
\IncMargin{-\parindent}

% Document starts
\begin{document}

% Title portion
\title{Some title}
\author{Some Author
\affil{Some University}}
\maketitle
\lstset{
    frame=tblr
    }

\begin{lstlisting}[caption = video tag in HTML5]
<video id=``movie" width=``640" height=``480">
</video>
\end{lstlisting}  
\end{document}
```

But I am not getting listings caption in a single line. It displays caption like

```
Listing 1.
video
tag
in
HTML5
```

I think the caption width is somehow minimized. Any idea about how I could fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this has adverse effects on other parts of the document, but saying

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\tempdimen}{\textwidth}}
```

seems to solve the issue.

The `acmsmall` class uses `\tempdimen` to set the captions, but the captions built by `listings` don't set it to a sensible value and so use the default (which is zero).